# Why does Firefox struggle to render React animations while Chromium renders them without breaking a sweat?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, chromium, stress-test

If you go to this page and scroll down, a stress test of React animations takes place (there's just a lot of animations):
https://www.react-reveal.com/examples/common/flip/

When I scroll down in Chrome, it doesn't break a sweat. But in Firefox, I barely see the animations chop into view. I have the same browser extensions in both my Chrome and Firefox. Could there be other settings causing this difference in performance?

EDIT: Versioning

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Browser:

  - Firefox 64.0
  - Chromium 71.0.3578.80

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behavior. Are both browsers "clean" (I mean, no extensions, no cache, etc)? What are the versions of each browser?

Comment: Great question. Both browsers have the same extensions. But even after disabling all plugins in Firefox, it still lags for me. I've updated the original post with software versions.